# Accordion of JavaFX trouble

Tags: css, javafx, accordion

I'm new at `JavaFX` , I want to give padding to `accordion` , and I change `CSS` of accordion like

```
.titled-pane {
    -fx-skin: "com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TitledPaneSkin";    
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-base-color;
    -fx-padding: 0.5em;
}
```

But bottom of accordion isn't visible, what I have to do?

[image]

Comment: check to the height or overflow properties

Comment: [capian css](https://code.google.com/p/javafx-demos/source/browse/trunk/javafx-demos/src/main/resources/styles/caspian/caspian_2.1_GA.css?r=17%E2%80%8F) I didn't find any overflow or height properties...